# How to find state-space representation for an estimated HMM model in R

Tags: r, hidden-markov-model, state-space-models

Take the toy (already estimated) HMM model below from the R package MSwM. How do I find a state-space representation for it? Put differently, what are the matrixes: ${G}_t,F_t,R_t,Q_t$ in the *observation*- and *state-equations* below?

$\mathbf{Y_t}=G_t \mathbf{X_t}+\mathbf{W_t}$, where $\mathbf{W_t}$~$WN(\mathbf{0},${$R_t$}),

$\mathbf{X_{t+1}}=F_t \mathbf{X_t}+\mathbf{V_t}$, where $\mathbf{V_t}$~$WN(\mathbf{0},${$Q_t$}), and $E(\mathbf{W_tV_s^{'}})=0$ for all $s$ and $t$.

```r
library(MSwM)
data(example)
mod=lm(y~x,example)
mod.mswm=msmFit(mod,k=2,p=1,sw=c(TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE),control=list(parallel=FALSE))
summary(mod.mswm)
```

Comment: Can I ask what do you mean by "finding a state-space representation of an HMM"? The state in HMM takes value in a finite set, while in state-space equations, it takes value in R^x

Comment: @NathanExplosion: I am not sure I understand the question, but I am new to HMMs so if I wrote something that doesn't make sense, please clarify with a few more details.

Comment: If your question is one of "Why do I care what the state-space representation is?" then here I would say "imagine that I want to use the Kalman filter to obtain the one-step predictor and error covariance **by hand** for this particular model. To do that, I need to know the matrices G,F,R, and Q.

Comment: All right. In that case, you don't need to use Kalman filter to solve for HMMs. You can simply use Viterbi algorithm to solve the problem. Please keep in mind that HMMs and state-space models are different: One is of finite state, while the other is of state in $\mathbb{R}^x$.

Comment: @NathanExplosion: HMMs are a type of state-space models.

Comment: @NathanExplosion: The first thing we should reconcile is what is discussed here https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/135573/198058 and described here https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~bee/courses/scribe/lec_09_25_2013.pdf I will digest these and get back.

Comment: In the lecture note /lec_09_25_2013.pdf you gave, they already said "These models differ from Hidden Markov Models in that ... has a stationary distribution." I would like to emphasis again that HMMs and state-space model are different models used in different scenarios. They are different collections of random variables in time. To the best of my knowledge, I do not know any explict conversion from HMM coefficients to state-space coefficients.